# Dell Latitude E6520 - Windows 10 will not detect camera - 0xA00F4224

Tags: windows-10, drivers, camera

I have Dell Latitude E6520, with Windows 10 Pro 64 bit.
When I try to use the Camera app, I get error `0xA00F4224`.
I also cannot find the camera on Device Manager. I tried to install the camera's driver from Dell website, but there are no drivers for Windows 10 for this device, and when I tried Windows 8 and 7, I couldn't find a driver for the camera.

The same things happens with the microphone .

What can I do?

Thank's

Comment: This Dell Community [page](https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/E6520-webcam/td-p/4613483) includes instructions on how to check the systems BIOS if the camera is enabled or not. On this other Community [page](https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/Latitude-E6520-camera-webcam/td-p/5162256?ref=l) there is, in 1 Reply, a link to a possible camera driver

Comment: Thank you! The problem was with the BIOS. I enabled camera and microhpone, and now the camera works. But the microphone doesn't work yet. Do you hava idea of what can I do?